# If x <> Int(x) always true, even if x=Int(x). Can't find out why

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty amateur at coding, but I'm trying to develop some automated business sheets in excel to make my old man's life a little easier on the business.
The intent is to create a table with range based on a number in a userform.
Code looks like this: (textbox1 was renamed to nParc)

```
Private Sub Cmb1_Click()

Dim nP As Variant

    nP = UserForm1.nParc.Value

If nP = "" Then
    MsgBox "Error 0"
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(nP) Then
    MsgBox "Error 1"
ElseIf Not nP > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error 2"
ElseIf nP <> Int(nP) Then
    MsgBox "Error 3"
Else
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(nP, 14).Address()), xlYes).Name = "Business"
End If

End Sub
```

I always get

> Error 3

when I click the "Proceed" button, no matter what. If I remove the msgbox "error 3" and the else after, it works.

I have already tried using `ElseIf Not nP = Int(nP)`, but the issue remains.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: what's the number in the useform?

Comment: The number I'm inserting in userform usually ranges from 2 to 5. It will define the table size, so it is always positive and whole.

Comment: See what happens when you change to `Dim nP As String`.

Comment: Ok, so apparently Dim nP As String solves it.
Would you mind explaining or pointing me somewhere I can get the explanation of why that is so?
Anyways, thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: You really shouldn't do `Dim nP As String` though... give me some time to add an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your textbox is returning text, not a number. It is best to cast the value to a numeric type before attempting to do any sort of numeric comparison:

```vb
If Len(nP) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "Error 0" ' blank string
   Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNumeric(nP) Then
   MsgBox "Error 1" ' not numeric
   Exit Sub
End If

' We've established it's numeric
Dim testValue As Double
testValue = CDbl(nP)

If testValue <> Int(testValue) Then
   MsgBox "Error 3"  ' has decimals
   Exit Sub
End If

' You could also possibly check if it's a valid row number
' i.e. that it's not too big
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me elaborate on the answer @bigben has provided and explain what exactly is going on.

### The Comparison

If you look at the value types of `np` and `Int(np)` using the `VarType` function, you will see that `VarType(np) = 8`, i.e. `np` is a String, and `VarType(Int(np)) = 5`, i.e. `Int(np)` is a Double. Since both are declared as a Variant---`Int` returns a Variant according to the [paragraph 6.1.2.3.1.18 of the language specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/db6d8be7-82cd-423c-83cb-3e6eff0a3363)---, the special case at the end of [paragraph 5.6.9.5 of the language specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/f8acd631-55c1-4199-bc1e-022aaab6d9c8) is triggered.

> There is an exception to the rules in the preceding table when both operands have a declared type of Variant, with one operand originally having a value type of String, and the other operand originally having a numeric value type. In this case, the numeric operand is considered to be less than (and not equal to) the String operand, regardless of their values.

This is why the comparison returns `False`

### The Numeric Check

You might wonder why `IsNumeric(np) = True` although `np` is a String. This is actually a bug in the VBA standard library. According to [paragraph 6.1.2.7.1.8 of the language specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/d920bc45-c366-4151-97dc-58c6a5b82780), `IsNumeric` should return `False` whenever the value type of the variable is String. However, in reality it seems to try to convert to `Double` and returns whether that was successful.

### The Remediation

As @bigben already mentioned, you should cast the input from the TextBox to another type. It works, if you just declare `np` as String, although assigning to a Variable of type Double after the IsNumeric check would be more appropriate.